# Atomic enque and dque operation

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, message-queue

One of my project has a requirement to have an atomic enqueue and dequeue operation in a kernel module. Please let me know are there any APIs to do this.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

The queue implementation in Linux kernel is called kfifo.
You may check the `include/linux/kfifo.h` or get it as a man page via

> % scripts/kernel-doc -man include/linux/kfifo.h | man -l -

You may do things atomically by wrapping them. You may use RCU, spinlock, mutex, or what is suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks for relpy Andy Shevchenko